# Как удалить текст из большого количества элементов?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

У меня есть код, который содержит большое количество тэгов(span-ы там разные и т.д). Как мне удалить текст из всех них разом, не вводя innerHTML = "", для каждого, а то масштабно выйдет, да и в костыли лезть не хочется.
**Пробовал объединить их в div и стереть innerHTML-ем, но не помогло**

Comment: Дать всем этим спанам и остальным тегам общий класс.

Comment: Если у вас уже есть массив этих элементов, то пройдите по нему циклом и тогда innerHTML будет написано в одном месте. Если такой подход не пойдёт, то поясните в чём проблема с множественным innerHTML.

Comment: Реализация напрямую зависит от структуры всех этих "span-ов и прочего"...

Comment: У меня не массив элементов, у меня просто в коде html-я идут строчные элементы. В ООП я не разбираюсь, но если не будет идей, то придётся поучить чутка.

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что это просто "невозможно".

Вы хотите удалить их все разом, но для начала их все разом нужно получить, а любой вариант создаст лишь nodeList, к которому вы потом сможете обратится вроде  nodeList[0] и тд.

Получив этот псевдо массив нужно как минимум перебрать, что бы как вы сказали "много". не писать ручками.

Идея такова, что мы получаем ноду и на каждой итерации удаляем текст изменив  textContent.

Вы конечно можете как-то отсортировать это тем же  sort, но смысл? Вам же не важно в каком порядке удалять. Задача просто удалить!

Код читается сверху вниз "а не разом", как вы сказали. Но  js  выполняет это на столько быстро, что для вас это меньше секунды.

В связи с этим я не вижу проблемы удалить/изменить текст, предварительно получив его и на каждой итерации пройтись по  node.

```
class="delText" - Это в классы.   

//JS
const delText = document.querySelectorAll('.delText'); 
 
for(const element of delText) { 
   element.textContent = 'ваш  text';
} 

delText[33].textContent = 'ваш  text';
```

Вы можете проверять условие и не просто удалять текст, но на определенном этапе и изменять его.

```
for(let i = 0; i<delText.lenght; i++) {   
   if(i<3 && i>1) { 
      element.textContent = 'Другой текст.';
   } 

   else if(i>4) { 
      element.textContent = 'Остальной текст';
   }
}
```

Comment: На самом деле очень элегантное решение, но у меня не заработало. Похоже, что я самого начала не так код писал.